# Loopback update embedded documents

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopbackjs

Here the models :

I want to do an update of "FirstLevel" from "Master" with the "prop" as search criteria.

```
{
   "name": "Master",
   "base": "PersistedModel",
   "properties": {}
   },
   "validations": [],
   "relations": {
       "firstLevels": {
           "type": "embedsMany",
           "model": "FirstLevel"
       }
   },
   "acls": [],
   "methods": []
}

{
   "name": "FirstLevel",
   "base": "PersistedModel",
   "properties": {
        "prop": {
            "type": "number"
         }
   },
   "validations": [],
   "relations": {},
   "acls": [],
   "methods": []
}
```

With MongooseJS I can do it like this :

```
Master.update({'firstLevels.prop': 100},
     {
          $push: {
               'firstLevels.$.prop2': 'test'
          }
     }, { upsert: true },
          function (err) {
               ...
          }
     );
```

How can I do this with Loopback?

Answer (score 4):

Fabien answered this question in the mailing list:

`Loopback` currently doesn't provide native `MongoDB` update commands like `$push` and so forth, so your best bet would be to use the connector directly - like:

```
var mongodb = app.dataSources.db.connector;
mongodb.collection('Master').update( ... );
```

Comment: I tried your solution but mongodb.collection(...) gives me undefined. And according to documentation you can't use mongodb connector
http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/MongoDB+connector#MongoDBconnector-UsingtheMongoDBconnector
any ideas?